# Angularjs ng-repeat for each unique ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to AngukarJS and ionic framework, I am trying to create an app with the following tree structure:

```
Home Tab (list of books) (templates/allbooks.html)
> unique book (book description and chapters) (templates/book-des.html)
>> unique chapter (templates/book-chapter.html)
```

here is the content of `books.js`

```
.factory('Books', function() {

  // books data
  var books = [{
    id: 0,
    title: 'Sample Title',
    author: 'Sample Author',
    category: 'Horor, Fiction',
    cover: '/cover.jpeg',
    details: 'some details about the book',
    chapters: [
      {
        id : 1,
        name: 'Chapter 1',
        filename: 'chapter1.html',
      },
      {
        id : 2,
        name: 'Chapter 2',
        filename: 'Chapter2.html',
      }
    ]
  }
  .....


    return {
     ...
    // get the book ID
    get: function(bookId) {
      for (var i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        if (books[i].id === parseInt(bookId)) {
          return books[i];
        }
      }
      return null;
    },
    // get the chapter ID
    getChapter: function(chapterId){
      for(var j = 0; j < books.chapters.length; j++){
        return j;
      }
      return null;
    }
  };
```

with the following `controllers.js`

```
....
.controller('BookDesCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Books) {
  $scope.book = Books.get($stateParams.bookId);
})
.controller('BookChapterCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Books) {
  $scope.book = Books.get($stateParams.bookId);
  // this returns error for getting chapter ID
  $scope.chapter = Books.getChapter($stateParams.chapterId);
})
.....
```

in the `templates/allbooks.html` I have the following `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="book in books">
  <p>{{book.title}}</p>
  <p>{{book.author}}</p>
  <p>{{book.category}}</p>
</div>
```

which successfully list all the books

in the `templates/book-des.html` I have the following `ng-repeat`

```
<div class="book-title">
   <p>{{book.title}}</p>
</div>
....
<div ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters">
      <ion-item href="#/tab/books/chapter/{{book.id}}/{{chapter.id}}">
        <p>{{chapter.name}}</p>
      </ion-item>
</div>
```

which gets the "current" book title and list all chapters. 
Everything is good so far

but in the `templates/book-chapter.html` I want to be able to show contents related to that specific chapter.

I tried using `ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters.id"` but it is not working.

**Main question is here:**

in `templates/book-chapter.html` template:

```
<div ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters.id">
      <ion-item class="item item-text-wrap">
      <p><div ng-include="'{{chapter.filename}}'"></div></p>
      </ion-item>
      <p> chapter ID is {{chapter.id}} </p>
</div>
```

How can I use the `ng-repeate` in that template to to pull out the information related to that unique chapter?

Comment: why you have `ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters.id` and not `ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters` ?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis because using `ng-repeat="chapter in book.chapters` will list "all" chapters. I just want to list the info of the chapter which the user clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template Update

```
  <ion-item class="item item-text-wrap">
  <p><div ng-include="'{{chapter.filename}}'"></div></p>
  </ion-item>
  <p> chapter ID is {{chapter.id}} </p>
```

Update your controller -
.

```
controller('BookChapterCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Books) {
 var book =  Books.get($stateParams.bookId);
  $scope.book = book;
  // this returns error for getting chapter ID
  $scope.chapter = Books.getChapter(book, $stateParams.chapterId);
})
```

Update your app.js

```
getChapter: function(book, chapterId) {
  for (var i = 0; i < book.chapters.length; i++) {
    if (book.chapters[i].id === parseInt(chapterId)) {
      return book.chapters[i];
    }
  }
  return null;
```

}

Comment: is this the modification to `templates/book-des.html`?

Comment: You have updated the question. I have to update my answer as well.

Comment: Simply, update your templates/book-chapter.html with the above.

Comment: unfortunately it doesnt return any of the info for that chapter, anything I need to add to controller?

Comment: Before that, please tell me in your book-des.html,  book.chapters returns only chapters of a particular book or all the books?

Comment: it should return the chapters and desc of a particular book. For example I have a book called Sample which has 4 chapters. `book-des.html` will list a description and all chapters of that book. User clicks "chapter 1" and goes to `book-chapter.html` and now the info for chapter 1 is displayed. If user clicked chapter 2, info for chapter 2 would be in `book-chapter.html`

Comment: I had the same thought in my mind. So see on iteration on books you get book object, You use that book object and do iteration on its chapter to get chapter object. Similarly, iterating on that chapter object should have yielded you the list of its sub-sections.

Comment: okay I updated the `books.js` in the question, I initially thought the same thing, so was planning to do another iteration to get chapter ID, but I am kind of lost. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: I got the issue. Wait fixing it.

Comment: I have updated the solution above. Can you please check?

Comment: Are you ok to start a chat session. It will be easier and faster to resolve the issue

Comment: also to double check when you said "Update your app.js" you meant "books.js" right?

Comment: Yes. I am starting a chat session. Lets nail it down over there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80328/discussion-between-nikhil-and-rain-man).